# Correct design to prevent blackscreen issue in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, architecture, jframe, swingworker

In my application I have a main frame window `GUI`, that launches a task in an `executor` service.

The submitted task `generates` output and stores `in a file on Disk`.

As soon as the o/p is generated GUI (observer) is informed of the o/p generated.

Here the problem is I am keeping a wait loop inside the main frame and as soon as a notification is received, the main panel is repainted on the main frame.

For small tasks this works fine, but as the size  of the threaded task increases. The wait loop time increases and the GUI main window turns black till computations are done.

Can you please help me in correcting the design. Also How can a `SwingWorker` thread help in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The wait loop time increases and the GUI main window turns black till computations are done.

Then you long running task is executing on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT) which prevents the GUI from repainting itself. You need to execute the long running task in a separate Thread. A SwingWorker is a separate Thread which has an API that also allows you to execute code on the EDT as required, for example when the code finishes executing or when you have intermediate results.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information. You can always search the forums for example of using a SwingWorker.

Comment: Ahem, the OP clearly stated that "I am keeping a wait loop inside the main frame". That's what's keeping the EDT busy, while the task is ran on an executor thread, again as the OP clearly stated in the first sentence. This answer has the right spirit, but seems you didn't read the question attentively enough. Also, `SwingWorker` is **not** a completely separate thread, they use an executor service as well.

Comment: @Ordous, `Also, SwingWorker is not a completely separate thread, they use an executor service as well` - the implementation is irrelevant. The important part is that the background task executes on a separate Thread, NOT the EDT. The point of my answer is that you should NOT be blocking/waiting on EDT since the GUI can't respond to events and do repainting.

Answer (score 2):

1)
Wait loops are the bane of all that is GUI. They are OK in other threads you have spawned, tricky in Executors (as they sometimes have limits on number of Threads, depending on which you use), and are completely out of the question on the EDT. That is the reason for your "blackscreen"

2)
Instead of using a custom (I assume it's custom) signal protocol and a wait loop, you could use one of the utility classes in Swing. For example, `SwingUtilities` has a couple of nice methods - `invokeLater` and `invokeAndWait` that take a `Runnable` and execute it on the EDT as soon as they can. Using this instead of the signal you have will allow you to not block the EDT and make your GUI responsive.

3)
If you really want to use a `SwingWorker`you may want to look through the documentation for it. It is essentially a way to do background tasks and report progress or completion/result to the EDT. Currently it uses an `ExecutorService` with 2 background threads, so having a lot of long running tasks on them is not a good idea (they will block each other). When creating a `SwingWorker` you would specify the method to be ran *in the background*, the method to be ran *on the EDT* when intermediate results are available, and the method to be ran *on the EDT* when you're finished either successfully or in error.

4) 
This does not pertain to the question at hand, but if you ever get into a situation where you need a wait loop in the EDT and cannot avoid it using another design or technique, you can always switch to using a `Timer`. It can be setup to be called every x milliseconds without blocking the EDT and turned off once you are satisfied with some condition.

Comment: Since my wait loop depends on the very first output generated by thread wi th many more to follow i think 4th suggestion is going to be helpful. Thanks :)