# ProgressBar properychangeListener not updating in this case

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, observer-pattern, propertychangelistener

I have a static boolean variable **inProgress** in a `MainPanel` containing a progressbar. A communicator class changes the value of this variable to true false.

The propertyListener is as follows

```
          @Override
          public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

            System.out.println("Property change check none");
            if(true ==MainPanel.inProgress){
                progressInformationPanel.getProgressBar().setIndeterminate(true);
                progressInformationPanel.getCurrentProcesLabel().setText("Processing...");
            }
            else if(false ==MainPanel.inProgress){
                System.out.println("Property change check none" + false);
                progressInformationPanel.getProgressBar().setIndeterminate(false);
              progressInformationPanel.getCurrentProcesLabel().setText("Finished....");
            }
        }
    });
```

The communicator class is an observer. That is listening to some other class. Now as soon as there is a progress  communicator class updates the variable of the MainPanel but the `propertyChangeListener` does not act. I am not getting idea about why this is happening. Also please see my linked [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26218630/correct-design-to-prevent-blackscreen-issue-in-jframe) here

Here is the SSCCE

```
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    public static  boolean inProgress = true;
    private JProgressBar bar;
    public Communicator diplayFacade;
    public MainFrame() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        diplayFacade = new Communicator();
        bar = new JProgressBar();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(bar);
        addProgressListener();
    }



    public void addProgressListener(){
        bar.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

                if(true == MainFrame.inProgress){
                    System.out.println("Property change check none" + true);
                    bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                }
                else if(false ==MainFrame.inProgress){
                    System.out.println("Property change check none" + false);
                    bar.setIndeterminate(false);

                }


            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.diplayFacade.methodCalled();


    }

}
```

And the Communicator class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Communicator {



    public void methodCalled(){

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi");
        MainFrame.inProgress = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is the `inProgress` value changed?  How is the property change event generated?  Simply changing the state of a variable won't magically trigger a property change event...

Comment: @MadProgrammer Communicator class updates the MainPanel.inProgress to true or false. when the Communicator class receives a notification from classes it is observing and depending on this notification, updates the inProgress variable

Comment: So how does anybody know `inProgress` has changed?  Who triggers this property change event? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer added the sscce :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, I don't think you understand what the `PropertyChangeListener` actually does.  A `PropertyChangeListener` monitors for changes to the properties of the `Object` it is registered to.

This notification doesn't happen by chance or automatically, you need to provide it, normally via `PropertyChangeSupport` which helps you manage the `PropertyChangeListener`s and triggering events...

By adding a `PropertyChangeListener` to the `JProgressBar`, you are monitoring for changes to it, not your frame.  Equally, by modifying the state of the `JProgressBar` from within the `PropertyChangeListener`, you risk ending up in an infinite loop, as the object tries to notify you of the changes that you have already made, over and over again....

First of all, you really should avoid using `static` in this manner, it would be better to have an instance variable and a setter to change it's state.  You would need to pass a reference of the frame to those people interested in changing the state, which raises another issue, you really don't want to expose your elements of your program unnecessarily, so it would be better to encompass this functionality in some kind of interface, for example...

```
public interface Progressable {
    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener);
    public void setInProgress(boolean inProgress);
    public boolean isInProgress();
}
```

Then you implement this interface.  The `Communicator` would then take a reference to an instance of the this interface and call `setInProgress` as required, for example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements Progressable {

    private JProgressBar bar;
    public Communicator diplayFacade;
    private boolean inProgress;

    public MainFrame() {
        diplayFacade = new Communicator(this);
        bar = new JProgressBar();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(bar);
        addPropertyChangeListener("inProgress", new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                if (isInProgress()) {
                    bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                } else {
                    bar.setIndeterminate(false);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void setInProgress(boolean value) {
        if (inProgress != value) {

            inProgress = value;
            firePropertyChange("inProgress", !inProgress, inProgress);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isInProgress() {
        return inProgress;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new MainFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the working solution**. Thanks to the inputs from **MadProgrammer**. had to add a `PropertyChangeSupport` to keep check on when the `inProgress` Property has changed.

```
package progressbarPoc;

import java.awt.DisplayMode;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;


public class MainFrame extends JFrame{

    public PropertyChangeSupport propertChangeSupport;
    public boolean inProgress;
    private JProgressBar bar;
    public Communicator diplayFacade;
    private PropertyChangeListener listener;
    public MainFrame() {
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        diplayFacade = new Communicator();
        diplayFacade.frame = this;
        bar = new JProgressBar();
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        add(bar);
        addProgressListener();
        propertChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this);


        addListener();

        bar.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
        this.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {
        this.propertChangeSupport.addPropertyChangeListener(listener);
    }



    public void fireProperty(boolean oldValue , boolean newValue){
        this.propertChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("inProgress", oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public void addProgressListener(){

        System.out.println("Here");





    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainFrame frame = new MainFrame();
        frame.diplayFacade.methodCalled();


    }


    public void addListener(){


        listener = new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                addPropertyChangeListener(this);
                if(true == inProgress){
                    System.out.println("Property change check none" + true);
                    bar.setIndeterminate(true);
                }
                else if(false ==inProgress){
                    System.out.println("Property change check none" + false);
                    bar.setIndeterminate(false);

                }

            }
        };
    }

}
```

And the Communicator class

```
package progressbarPoc;

import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Communicator {

    public MainFrame frame;

    public void methodCalled(){

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Hi");
        frame.inProgress = true;

        frame.fireProperty(frame.inProgress, !frame.inProgress);
    }

}
```

Comment: You should not be using `frame.fireProperty`, you should be using some kind setter which triggers the state change, it is not the responsibility of the `Communicator` to trigger events...also `frame` would be `null` in your example...

Comment: @MadProgrammer No why will framebe null In MainPanel I have assigned " diplayFacade.frame = this" I ahev kept it public. Although should be private and have getters and setters

Comment: That's even worse...you've exposed your class to another class that shouldn't be allowed to access it

Comment: @MadProgrammer frame.fireProperty calls a method in MainFrame that actually firesProperty. Please don't get confused by name they mey be misleading. Also it is working absolutely fine. I have tested.

Comment: But it's still the same thing. Communicator should not be responsible for notifying the source that it's property has changed, it's beyond its scope of its responsibility. I'd encourage you to look into the concept of programming to interface, you've tightly coupled your class together, they can't operate without each other which breaks down the concept of reusability.

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes agreed This was just a POC actual implementation is going to be totally different :)

Comment: You shouldn't be modify the state of the object your are monitoring as this could trigger and infinite loop ending in stake overflow...